# Error in conversion from Character to its Unicode number

Tags: haskell, unicode, syntax-error

I am trying to code in Haskell. I want to construct a code in which user inputs the character and computer tells its Unicode number.My code is below.But it does not generates output and display the error message.How can i remove error from my code. Please help me to solve this problem.

Code:

```
module Code where

Ord :: Char -> Int

Ord c = ...
```

Error Message:

```
ERROR file:.\amina.hs:2 - Syntax error in declaration (unexpected `::')
```

Comment: Rename `Ord` to `ord`. A function name must not start with a capital letter.

Comment: There already is a predefined `ord` function, which does what you need. (Further, if you are using Hugs, you should know that it is ancient. Consider using GHC instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Haskell, function names must start with a lowercase letter. This is not merely a coding convention; it is part of the actual language syntax. If you try to use an uppercase letter for a function name, you'll get some very perplexing error messages.